# How to navigate to a different region layout using Prism and Unity?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, unity-container, prism

I'm writing a WPF application and using [Prism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648465.aspx) and [Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn170416.aspx) to navigate from screen to screen. The problem I've got is my screens have different region layout outs.

For example (please see the image), the 1st screen has 2 regions (region 1 and region 2) and when the user clicks a button it navigates to the 2nd screen which has only has 1 region (region 3).
[image]

I can't get it working. I've also tried hiding region 2, and injecting the 2nd screen into region 1. It hides region 2, but doesn't collapse it. So there is a big white space on the right hand side.

I found this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769024/wpf-prism-w-unity-collapse-or-hide-nav-menu-from-shell-before-login) on Stack Overflow that says have region in the Shell.xaml file, and create another region to display the multiple region layout.

So my **Shell.xaml** file looks like this:

```
<ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.ShellMainRegion}" />
```

And I register the regions, view models and views in the Initialize method of a class that implements the IModule interface.

```
_container.RegisterType<IRegion1And2ViewModel, Region1And2ViewModel>();
_container.RegisterType<IRegion1And2View, Region1And2View>();

_container.RegisterType<IRegion1ViewModel, Region1ViewModel>();
_container.RegisterType<IRegion1View, Region1View>();
_container.RegisterType<IRegion2ViewModel, Region2ViewModel>();
_container.RegisterType<IRegion2View, Region2View>();
_container.RegisterType<IRegion3ViewModel, Region3ViewModel>();
_container.RegisterType<IRegion3View, Region3View>();


IRegion shellMainRegion = _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.ShellMainRegion];

var region1And2VM = _container.Resolve<IRegion1And2ViewModel>();
IRegionManager region1And2RegionManager = shellMainRegion.Add(region1And2VM.View);

IRegion region1 = region1And2RegionManager.Regions[RegionNames.Region1];
IRegion region2 = region1And2RegionManager.Regions[RegionNames.Region2];

var region1VM = _container.Resolve<IRegion1ViewModel>();
var region2VM = _container.Resolve<IRegion2ViewModel>();
region1.Add(region1VM.View);
region2.Add(region2VM.View);
region1.Activate(region1VM.View);

var region3VM = _container.Resolve<IRegion3ViewModel>();
shellMainRegion.Add(region3VM.View);
```

When I run the app it shows the first screen fine (with regions 1 and 2).
But when I click the button and call the following code the region 1 and 2 layout remains and the Region 1 view is no longer displayed, and the region 3 view (which should be displayed in the shell main region) isn't displayed at all.

```
IRegion shellMainRegion = _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.ShellMainRegion];
shellMainRegion.RequestNavigate(typeof(Region3View).Name);
```

Can someone please show me the code I need to display screens with different region layouts using Prism and Unity?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, you should really be using the latest version of Prism, which is 6.3 at this time. The links you included in your question are for a version that is old, and not really supported any more. The latest bits can be found here: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism. You can add the latest version to your project/solution via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Unity/).

Now to your issue, navigation. You seem to have a reference to the region manager (`_regionManager`) in the code that is written to do the `RequestNavigate` call. But, you are not using is properly. Rather than grab a reference to the `ShellMainRegion`, simply call the `RequestNavigate` method off of the region manager.

`_regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.ShellMainRegion, typeof(Region3View).Name);`

What this does is tell the region manager to find the shell region, and  show `Region3View` in it.

So, this line of code:

`IRegion shellMainRegion = _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.ShellMainRegion];`

is no longer needed.

Hope this helps you out!